# iCal type text changing icon in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, icalendar

How can i change the text as iCal icon in iPhone do. I want to change the date in my app icon for iPhone.
I have an countdown app. I want to show the remaining days left as iCal shows the date. How is this possible in Objective-c?

Comment: You want to show this in App Icon?

Comment: Yes..Same as iCal icon shows the date i want to show the remaining days in icon.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `applicationIconBadgeNumber` . [UILocalNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)  lets you send send local notifications , which you can use to periodically update your application.

Comment: Thanks, but i don't want to set badge number i want similar to calendar icon in iPhone which displays the date on icon itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can display the day value in application icon.

For that, you have to use "applicationIconBadgeNumber" property of the app.

Make sure, it will accept only integer value. Means you can not display entire date format in that. You can only display no of day in app icon.

Hope it will be helpful to you.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks..But i don't want to set the badge number if you look in the calendar icon of the iPhone you can see the for today on icon Thursday and 27 is written i want something like that not the badge number.

Comment: Ok, that you can not do. Because, it is like you are changing the app icon continuously. Which you can't. Though if you get any useful help, let it share with me.